# Load another JavaScript file and acess var

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a work for school, and I'm doing a online plataforn to buy games online, I can just use HTML, CSS and JS so for each game e have a JS file with the informations, here is an example:

```
 /*doom.js*/
 var info = {
  title  : "doom",
  price : "59.99",
  off  : "0%"
};
```

And my html page is that one:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script src="games/functions.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
        <label id="title"></label>
</body>
</html>
```

I have that page to all my games, so I use the GET method to know wich file I need to read. (game.html?id=doom)

I have this code to get the id chosed and load the file:

```
window.onload = function() {
    id = getURLParameter('id');
    loadGamefile("games/"+id+".js");
};

function getURLParameter(name) {
    return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null;
}

function loadGamefile(filename){
    var fileref=document.createElement('script')
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
    fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
            
    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);

    loadinformation();
}

function loadinformation(){ 
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = info.title; //info.title is from the doom.js file
}
```

The only problem is he dont change the label, but if I put a button on the btml code and onclick I say its the loadinformation() he load fine, but I want that automatic when the page loads and here is the error I get from console: `functions.js:22 Uncaught ReferenceError: info is not defined`, I think maybe is becouse the browser didn't had time to load the file, I don't know, can someone help me? Thanks and sorry for my english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you aren't giving the browser a chance to parse your new script. You can give it a moment to do that using [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout).

```
function loadGamefile(filename) {
    // your other code goes here

    setTimeout(function() {
        loadinformation();
    }, 500); // wait half of a second
}
```

Ideally, you should have your data stored in a JSON file then load it using AJAX instead. There are numerous tutorials covering how to load JSON over AJAX.

As @Bergi pointed out, this solution is very fragile and relies on the script loading in under 500ms. Instead, you can [listen for the `load` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement#Dynamically_importing_scripts) to ensure you use the script as soon as it's ready.

```
function loadGamefile(filename) {
    var fileref=document.createElement('script')
    fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
    fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)

    if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
        document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);

    // Wait for the script to load
    fileref.onload = function() {
        loadinformation();
    };
}
```

Comment: thanks but I just can use HTML CSS and JS, I'll try that.

Comment: I tried that code but it didn't work anyway. Do you know another trick? I realy want put that to work

Comment: Sorry but actualy works, I just callend in the wrong spot, thanks so much for the help.

Comment: What if the file doesn't load in 500ms? That approach is so fragile. Why not use a proper onload handler?

Comment: @Bergi You're right, `onload` would be much better. I'll update the answer to better reflect that.

Comment: Why check you `typeof fileref` fot one code row, while each other row will be broken if it becomes to be undefined? Edit: Oh, sorry, I see - it's just a copy of the question.